# How can I restrict `pgfplots` plot to an interval manually?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

OK, I've plotted these graphs but am unable to stretch the second one, so that **they both have the same values on the vertical lines** drawn from one to another. I've tried to set `domain=0:2200` for both but it doesn't work.[image]

Comment: Howdy i find it quite hard to imagine what your code looks like. Maybe you should consider to produce a (minimal) example. But maybe the mentioning of   the `xmax` and `ymax` keys helps already . There is also a `restrict x domain` key.

Comment: @bloodworks: Sorry, always forget what really matters. `xmax`, `xmin` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try setting `xmin` and `xmax` (see `pgfplots` manual, section 4.14 *Specifying the plotted range*) to the same value for both plots. Naturally there is similarly `ymin`/`ymax` and `zmin`/`zmax` for the `y` and `z` axes, if needed.

Comment: I've got to say you've done well working out what the question was really about :-)